# Self-hosted next13 api routes slow third party api call

Tags: php, reactjs, next.js, postman

For the sake of simplicity, I will try to abstract the question as much as possible. I have a simple PHP API, which, when called from Postman, takes around 100ms to respond. I also have a Next.js 13 application. Because I want to keep my PHP API private, I have a couple of API routes (in Next.js) which are directed to the PHP API.

Here's where the problem arises: when I make a request from an API route, it takes around 1000ms to get the response, which is roughly 10 times slower than the Postman call. The strange thing is that if I make another request in the same API handler context, the second request is always super fast, like 20ms.

Initially, I thought that the problem might be due to the cold start of the API handler, but after several hours of research, I concluded that the self-hosted Next.js has a Node.js server and it's not serverless, so the cold start theory is invalid. I also tried calling another API (the free public Rick and Morty API), and there I get consistent results with Next.js API handlers and Postman (40ms on both platforms). So this leads me to believe the issue lies with my PHP API, but I'm really out of ideas on where to start debugging. Any help or suggestions would be greatly welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.